# How to Toggle post content within a "post" title in a page?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, toggle, posts

I'm trying to give all "posts" title in a specific page. So If someone clicks on that posts, it's content must be toggle below the title and if some clicks the title again then the content must hide.

I solved half of the problem with the help of WP-Archives Plugin. And my page is looking like this [Check this image here](http://oi57.tinypic.com/yguwm.jpg).. So these are
"Archives" titles links. And if someone clicks on it, it will take to the that.. I want the content in the particular posts to be in the same page in the form of toggle (in abvoe image..). Is it possible?

Comment: yes. with javascript and probably ajax, if you have too many posts in one page, you can do it.

Comment: Is the Jquery accordion an option? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing an accordion function. Wordpress offers a bunch of accordion plugins. Here are a few: 
http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/accordion

If you're looking for something with a little more control you might want to look straight into the jquery accordion widget. See information here: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

**EDIT**

To add the accordion plugin to your list, you'll need to apply the following changes. Add the following to your head tag:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

In your wp-archives plugin modify the following line:

```
echo "<div class='list'><ul>\n";
```

to this:

```
echo "<div class='list'><ul id=\"unique_id_of_your_choice\">\n";
```

As for the content that should follow each post title, You will need to update the plugin once again to include the archive post content(either the entire post or a snippet, whichever you choose). It should look something like this if the database field holding the content were named "post_content".

```
$arcresults2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_date, post_title, post_content, comment_status FROM " . $wpdb-> posts . " WHERE post_date LIKE '$thisyear-$thismonth-%' AND $current_posts AND post_status='publish' AND post_password='' ORDER BY post_date DESC");
...

...
$arc_title = $arcresult2->post_title;
$arc_content = $arcresult2->post_content;
...

...
echo "<li class='list'><a href=\"" . $url . "\" title=\"" . $title_text . "\">" . wptexturize($text) .  "</a>\n";
echo"<ul><li>".$arc_content."</li></ul></li>\n";
```

Comment: Yes, though the answer is useful but how can I implement in my problem? Like I've a page and I've used shortcut <!--wp_archives--> (from WP-ARCHIVES Plugin) so that it displays all the titles of archives in the website. I'm not perfect in PHP. If I'd have to implement the above given solution directly with the help of HTML then I'd have solved the problem. This answer is useful is indeed very much useful.. [Plugin Code](http://pastebin.com/EC3GP0kT)

Comment: To implement the jquery function within the wp-archives plugin, you'll need to change this line `echo "<div class='list'><ul>\n"; ` to `echo "<div id="unique_id_of_your_choice" class='list'><ul>\n";`. You'll also need to check that you are including the required jQuery libraries script and user interface. Once this is added, you can add a snippet of code on your page `$(function() {
    $( "#unique_id_of_your_choice" ).accordion();
  });`

Comment: To see an example of the script includes, visit http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ and click on "view source" below the example

Comment: It makes the plugin deactivated when I added "<div id="unique_id_of_your_choice" class='list'><ul>\n";. But once I have changed it to id='unique_id_of_your_choice' it activates again. But it's not working. I think the glitch is somewhat in including too many javascript files. Here is the [link]http://webguidesolutions.com/management/news/

Comment: yeah makes sense. I should of escaped my double quotations like so ` \" `. You need to add both the jQuery file and the jQuery-ui file to your page. The jQuery-ui file contains the needed accordion plugin. you can find it here http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js

Comment: Thanks for replying.. I'm not familiar with javascripts, so could you please copy those jquery script links which I've to include in the page as I see many jqyery scripts over there in the accordon view source page. Also I'm including the above mentioned scripts over there in Wordpress Page editor html but not in the page template. Do you also mean to include these scripts in the page tenplate?

Comment: just add this script tag in your head tag `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks.. I see some changes in that page. Now whenever I try to click on any link, instead of toggling down it is not moving to that page. Actually it is happening nothing when I click on any link

Comment: Awesome! I just updated the plugin and I see the content beneath  the title in the same div. But toggling is not working..

Comment: I feel I can solve this issue from now. I will try to do it looking at the example as I have found almost 80% solution. I wasn't able to get the content part which was hard for me. Now It got it. I will try to make it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with an accordion script like [jQueryUI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/), but if you want to apply this to your posts page, you will also have to edit your page template.

Here is one simple method (see [source](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/open-posts-as-accordion-on-front-page)):

---

1) Add the following to your theme's functions.php

```
function add_accordion_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script('acc', get_template_directory_uri() . '/acc.js', array('jquery-ui-accordion'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_accordion_script');
```

2) Create acc.js in your themes directory thus:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            header: "div.accordion-header",
            collapsible: true,
            active:false });
});
```

3) Finally modify your theme page to something like this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
    <div id="accordion">
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
        <div class="accordion-header">
            <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
            <?php the_excerpt();?>
        </div>
    <div><?php the_content();?></div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php else:?>
    <p><?php _e('No posts'); ?></p>
<?php endif;?>
```

---

Depending on your wordpress template this may be more complicated to implement than is outlined above... in which case you'd have to provide more information.

Another alternative would be to use some sort of plugin specifically designed for this purpose. I found three that might work for you, but they do not seem to be well supported/maintained... so the above method may still be your best option:

1. [Wordpress jQuery Accordion Plugin](http://www.jeffikus.com/shop/wordpress-jquery-accordion-plugin/)
2. [WP Post Accordion](https://github.com/johnciacia/wp-post-accordion)
3. [Read More Right Here Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/read-more-right-here/)

Comment: Thanks for the more information. Let me try my best to work on the above mentioned tricks...

Answer (score 0):

[Collapse-O-Matic Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-collapse-o-matic/) for wordpress is another alternative for this which is working like a charm for my website but only if I'm changing it to default theme of Wordpress :(. Seems like there is any glitch in my theme. Anyways, thanks for all the responses posted above.